# Need to take data from column B and add the corresponding date to new columns in google sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, indexing, filter, google-query-language

[I have 3000+ rows of data like this.  I need Columns to be Last Name, First Name, Card Number.  I have tried =IF(A3 = "Last Name:", B3) which works but I have a bunch of FALSE cells.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBbgN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to prevent FALSE use:

```
=IF(A3 = "Last Name:", B3, )
```

for array use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A3:A = "Last Name:", B3:B, ))
```

or you can use filter:

```
=FILTER(B3:B, A3:A="Last Name:")
```